# P/Invoke C++ Class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mono, pinvoke

I want to use [rasterbar libtorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/) in a C# application. It's written in unmanaged C++.

I'm new at using DLLs and found this article online: [How to Marshal a C++ Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class)

It describes that it's not possible to marshal/invoke a C++ class directly and you have to write a bridge in C (or managed C++) in order to use the library in managed C# code.

The article is from 2007 and I wonder if there is a better solution to use C++ DLLs by now. I'm looking for solutions that also work on the Mono platform. `libtorrent` is cross plattform so it should be possible.

Comment: What about http://www.monotorrent.com/.

Comment: Already watch that project on Github. However libtorrent seems to be more advanced. Going to use MonoTorrent if I can't get libtorrent to work.

Comment: Basically there aren't any breakthrough since that article.The best way is to program the only subset of the function that you need(helpers) and expose it via C to C#.

Answer (score 2):

First you should have the **libtorrent** dll built for windows. [This link here](http://softwerkz.net/2009/09/libtorrent/) can help you. Then for calling the un-managed code (C++ in this case) from the managed code (C# in this case) you can use [Platform Invocation Services (PInvoke)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It allows managed code to call unmanaged functions that are implemented in a DLL. For example have a look on this MSDN code

```
// PInvokeTest.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    public static extern int puts(string c);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    internal static extern int _flushall();

    public static void Main() 
    {
        puts("Test");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```

The better approach will be to write a wrapper class in C# for **libtorrent** dll, wrap it's methods using PInvoke and use the wrapper throughout your project.